# Are the shared preferences associated with the App deleted when the app is removed?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

Are `SharedPreferences` value for an App retained even after it is removed?

If not, I would like to retain the `SharedPreferences` even after the app is uninstalled/removed. Is there a way?

Edit: I am reluctant to store the settings on the SD Card. Is there a way I can store them in the phone memory itself?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SharedPreferences are deleted when an app is uninstalled, but you can use the [BackupManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/backup/BackupManager.html) to perform a backup into the cloud - Reto Meier has a good [blog post](http://blog.radioactiveyak.com/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location-part-2-being.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20TheRadioactiveYak%20%28The%20Radioactive%20Yak%29) for getting you started.

This approach means if a user installs you app onto a new phone they can have their preferences copied over to there as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes shared preferences are stored in the data directory for the application.  When the app is uninstalled the file is removed.

If you want to retain a shared preferences you'll need to work with a file on the sd card.

Comment: I'm really reluctant to save it in the sd card. Is there no other way?

Answer (score 0):

Yes they will get deleted. You would have to store a backup on SD card and restore it upon re-installation.