# Android: one time only variable storing

Tags: android, storage, sharedpreferences

I have an appliaction which will show a welcome window only the first time the user starts the app. What would be the best way to store this boolean variable (i.e. "isFirstTime") to phone storage? Should I use [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) or [Internal Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal)?

The docs say that if I use Internal Storage my "preference" file will automatically get removed upon uninstallation which is quite handy.

I want a clean, simple and fast solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,  I'd recommend using Shared Preferences. Basically you could put a shared preference with a key of "isFirstTime" and a type of boolean set to false.  Then in your main activity do something like:

```
getBoolean (isFirstTime, true);
```

This, if it can't find isFirstTime will give you true, allowing you to do an if-statement based on the result.

Comment: Thank you. So I will go with this I guess.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that SharedPreferences would probably be the most "clean, simple, and fast solution" that you are looking for.  SharedPreferences are also deleted when the application is uninstalled.

[Are the shared preferences associated with the App deleted when the app is removed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6907916/are-the-shared-preferences-associated-with-the-app-deleted-when-the-app-is-remov)

Answer (score 1):

`SharedPreferences` are your best option for this.